# Building a Netbeans lexer for ANTLR 4.5 and String Template 4 grammars

Tags: netbeans, antlr4, lexer, stringtemplate-4

I have been trying to build a Lexer in Netbeans 8.2 to have the correct syntax for String Template v4 files. The problem is that Netbeans modules only have access to ANTLR 3.3 or 4.5 libraries, and I cannot find any String template v4, either pre compiled or needing to be compiled, Lexer grammar files to work with.

Does anyone know of any String Template v4 grammar files that can be built with ANTLR 3.3 or 4.5? I have attached my code and sample that are working with ANTLR 4.5 and [this set of grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/stringtemplate).

**EDIT 1:**

Someone in the comments asked for some examples and what I have tried so far.I have tried using the String template Lexer from [here](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4). I took the code from the compile section of the source and it seemed to work ok, but it was very buggy since it was built with ANTLR 3.5 and I was trying to have it run with ANTRL 3.3. The syntax coloring worked, but it was having trouble reading files and sometimes outright failed.

My second attempt was with [this set of grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/stringtemplate). They load all of the files properly since I could compile it with 4.5, but the syntax coloring is completely off. It looks like the grammars are more so built for Java than String Template v4.

Here is the code I currently am working with to build the Lexer in the Netbeans module:

Language Provider:

```
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.InputAttributes;
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.Language;
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.LanguagePath;
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.Token;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LanguageEmbedding;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LanguageProvider;

/**
 *
 * @author Cory
 */
@org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider(service=org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LanguageProvider.class)
public class stLanguageProvider extends LanguageProvider {

    @Override
    public Language<?> findLanguage(String mimeType) {
        if ("text/x-st".equals(mimeType)){
            return new stLanguageHierarchy().language();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public LanguageEmbedding<?> findLanguageEmbedding(Token<?> token, LanguagePath languagePath, InputAttributes inputAttributes) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Language Hierarchy:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.Language;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LanguageHierarchy;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.Lexer;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LexerRestartInfo;

/**
 *
 * @author Cory
 */
public class stLanguageHierarchy extends LanguageHierarchy<stTokenId> {

    private static List<stTokenId> tokens = new ArrayList<stTokenId>();
    private static Map<Integer, stTokenId> idToToken = new HashMap<Integer, stTokenId>();

    private static final Language<stTokenId> language = new stLanguageHierarchy().language();

    public static Language<stTokenId> getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    static {
        TokenType[] tokenTypes = TokenType.values();
        for (TokenType tokenType : tokenTypes) {
            tokens.add(new stTokenId(tokenType.name(), tokenType.category, tokenType.id));
        }
        for (stTokenId token : tokens) {
            idToToken.put(token.ordinal(), token);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an actual stTokenId from an id. This essentially allows
     * the syntax highlighter to decide the color of specific words.
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    static synchronized stTokenId getToken(int id) {
        return idToToken.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<stTokenId> createTokenIds() {
        return tokens;
    }

    @Override
    protected Lexer<stTokenId> createLexer(LexerRestartInfo<stTokenId> lri) {
        return new stEditorLexer(lri);
    }

    @Override
    protected String mimeType() {
        return "text/x-st";
    }
}
```

The Editor lexer: This is where the String Template Lexer should be brought in if I can find it. This code here is using the lexer from ANTLR 4.5 build from the [second link](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/stringtemplate).

```
import org.antlr.parser.st4.STLexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.Lexer;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LexerInput;
import org.netbeans.spi.lexer.LexerRestartInfo;
import org.openide.util.Exceptions;

/**
 *
 * @author Cory
 */
public class stEditorLexer implements Lexer<stTokenId> {

    private static final String SOURCE_NAME = "stEditor";

    private LexerRestartInfo<stTokenId> lri;
    private STLexer lexer;

    public stEditorLexer(LexerRestartInfo<stTokenId> lri) {
        this.lri = lri;
        try
        {
            LexerInput lexerInput = lri.input();
            AntlrCharStream charStream = new AntlrCharStream(lexerInput, SOURCE_NAME);
            lexer = new STLexer(charStream);
            lexer.setDelimiters('$', '$');
            lexer.setChannel(STLexer.OFF_CHANNEL);
            lexer.reset();
            AntlrLexerState state = (AntlrLexerState) lri.state();

            if (state != null) {
                state.apply(lexer);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the next token recognized by the lexer or null if there are no
     *         more characters (available in the input) to be tokenized.
     */
    @Override
    public org.netbeans.api.lexer.Token<stTokenId> nextToken() {
        Token token = lexer.nextToken();

        stTokenId tokenId = null;

        if (token.getType() != LexerInput.EOF) {
            tokenId  = stLanguageHierarchy.getToken(token.getType());
            System.out.println("nextToken - " + tokenId.toString() + " " + token.getText());
        }  else if (lri.input().readLength() > 0) {
            // Remaining chars on the input should be tokenized
            // see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=240826
            tokenId = stLanguageHierarchy.getToken(STLexer.HORZ_WS);
            System.out.println("nextToken - ERROR (as WS)");
        }

        if (tokenId == null) {
            System.out.println("nextToken - EOF");
            return null;
        }

        // According to the method specification, this must *not* return any
        // other Token instances than those obtained from the TokenFactory.
        return lri.tokenFactory().createToken(tokenId);
    }

    @Override
    public Object state() {
        return new AntlrLexerState(lexer._mode, lexer._modeStack);
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {
    }
}
```

The TokenType class I generated from the Tokens from the second link as well:

```
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.Language;
import org.netbeans.api.lexer.TokenId;

/**
 *
 * @author Cory
 */
public enum TokenType implements TokenId {

    DOC_COMMENT(1, "other"),
    BLOCK_COMMENT(2, "comment"),
    LINE_COMMENT(3, "comment"),
    TMPL_COMMENT(4, "comment"),
    HORZ_WS(5, "other"),
    VERT_WS(6, "other"),
    ESCAPE(7, "separator"),
    LDELIM(8, "specialCharacter"),
    RBRACE(9, "separator"),
    TEXT(10, "text"),
    LBRACE(11, "separator"),
    RDELIM(12, "specialCharacter"),
    STRING(13, "string"),
    IF(14, "keyword"),
    ELSEIF(15, "keyword"),
    ELSE(16, "keyword"),
    ENDIF(17, "keyword"),
    SUPER(18, "keyword"),
    END(19, "keyword"),
    TRUE(20, "keyword"),
    FALSE(21, "keyword"),
    AT(22, "keyword"),
    ELLIPSIS(23, "keyword"),
    DOT(24, "separator"),
    COMMA(25, "separator"),
    COLON(26, "separator"),
    SEMI(27, "separator"),
    AND(28, "keyword"),
    OR(29, "keyword"),
    LPAREN(30, "separator"),
    RPAREN(31, "separator"),
    LBRACK(32, "separator"),
    RBRACK(33, "separator"),
    EQUALS(34, "separator"),
    BANG(35, "separator"),
    ERR_CHAR(36, "keyword"),
    ID(37, "keyword"),
    PIPE(38, "separator");

    public int id;
    public String category;
    public String text;

    private static final Language<stTokenId> langauge = new stLanguageHierarchy().language();

    private TokenType(int id, String category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public static TokenType valueOf(int id) {
        TokenType[] values = values();
        for (TokenType value : values) {
            if (value.id == id) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The id " + id + " is not recognized");
    }

    @Override
    public String primaryCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public static final Language<stTokenId> getLanguage() {
        return langauge;
    }
}
```

Everything else such as the AntlrCharStream is code that I found to work with the ANTLR 4.5 library.

**EDIT 2**
I thought adding some sample output would help to try and figure out what could be the problem.

[image: Sample of output]

This is the color scheme:

```
<fontcolor name="keyword"           foreColor="blue" default="default"/>
<fontcolor name="comment"           foreColor="green" default="default"/>    
<fontcolor name="other"             foreColor="gray" default="default"/>    
<fontcolor name="specialCharacter"  foreColor="orange" default="default"/> 
<fontcolor name="text"              foreColor="pink" default="default"/> 
<fontcolor name="string"            foreColor="red" default="default"/> 
<fontcolor name="separator"         foreColor="magenta" default="default"/>
```

Comment: Example of code or what you have tried so far?

Comment: The StringTemplate grammars in the Antlr repository are the correct grammars to use for an ST v.4.08 source editor. They are currently being used as the basis for the Eclipse StringTemplateDT editor (I am the author of both these grammars and Eclipse StDT editor.) If the syntax coloring is 'off', the problem almost certainly resides in the NetBeans implementing code.

Comment: @GRosenberg Ok. Are you talking about the sources from grammar-v4 repository? If so that looks an awful lot like java rather than String Template code. If that is the case where that is the correct code to use then I think the problem I was noticing was that new line characters were not being tokenized correctly. I know I have cross referenced a lot of examples and tutorials to build the netbeans Lexer code, and I did the same for the String Template Lexer code. So, I am not sure which could be wrong. Should I add some output of the syntax to see what could be wrong?